# Take common values in nested dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a nested dictionary, how can I get the values with common key values such as 37, 74, etc:

```
myDict = {0: {37.0:  {'C23H27O9': 'C22H23O10'}},
          1: {74.0:  {'C23H27O9': 'C21H19O11'}},
          2: {111.0: {'C23H27O9': 'C20H15O12'}},
          3: {148.0: {'C23H27O9': 'C19H11O13'}},
          4: {37.0:  {'C22H23O10': 'C21H19O11'}},
          5: {74.0:  {'C22H23O10': 'C20H15O12'}},
          6: {111.0: {'C22H23O10': 'C19H11O13'}},
          7: {37.0:  {'C21H19O11': 'C20H15O12'}},
          8: {74.0:  {'C21H19O11': 'C19H11O13'}},
          9: {37.0:  {'C20H15O12': 'C19H11O13'}}
         }
```

Desired output:

```
37.0 --> C23H27O9: C22H23O10: C21H19O11 : C20H15O12 : C19H11O13
74.0 --> C23H27O9 : C21H19O11 : C19H11O13
...
```

Comment: Please add the input data in a way that can be copied directly into a Python script (no images). The output data should also be in a valid Python format

Comment: I added the Python script.

Comment: Please also add the expected output in valid Python

Comment: Just to clarify, are you expected the output to be printed as shown or in a new data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby as gb
myDict = {0: {37.0: {'C23H27O9': 'C22H23O10'}}, 1: {74.0: {'C23H27O9': 'C21H19O11'}}, 2: {111.0: {'C23H27O9': 'C20H15O12'}}, 3: {148.0: {'C23H27O9': 'C19H11O13'}}, 4: {37.0: {'C22H23O10': 'C21H19O11'}}, 5: {74.0: {'C22H23O10': 'C20H15O12'}}, 6: {111.0: {'C22H23O10': 'C19H11O13'}}, 7: {37.0: {'C21H19O11': 'C20H15O12'}}, 8: {74.0: {'C21H19O11': 'C19H11O13'}}, 9: {37.0: {'C20H15O12': 'C19H11O13'}}}
d = sorted([(a, [j for k in b.items() for j in k]) for i in myDict.values() for a, b in i.items()], key=lambda x:x[0])
r = [(a, [*{i for _, j in b for i in j}]) for a, b in gb(d, key=lambda x:x[0])]
```

Output:

```
[(37.0, ['C19H11O13', 'C20H15O12', 'C21H19O11', 'C22H23O10', 'C23H27O9']), (74.0, ['C19H11O13', 'C20H15O12', 'C21H19O11', 'C22H23O10', 'C23H27O9']), (111.0, ['C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13', 'C23H27O9', 'C22H23O10']), (148.0, ['C23H27O9', 'C19H11O13'])]
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want the set of all keys and values from the innermost dictionaries, preserving the order in which they are encountered.

This seems like it does the job:

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
for _, outerDict in myDict.items():
    for innerKey, innerDict in outerDict.items():
        for k, v in innerDict.items():
            if k not in result[innerKey]:
                result[innerKey].append(k)
            if v not in result:
                result[innerKey].append(v)
```

After this, `result` is a `dict` of `list`s:

```
>>> for key, values in result.items():
>>>    print(key, values)

37.0 ['C23H27O9', 'C22H23O10', 'C21H19O11', 'C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13']
74.0 ['C23H27O9', 'C21H19O11', 'C22H23O10', 'C20H15O12', 'C19H11O13']
111.0 ['C23H27O9', 'C20H15O12', 'C22H23O10', 'C19H11O13']
148.0 ['C23H27O9', 'C19H11O13']
```

You can format that output however you like, my assumption is that you just want the data.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but your output does not include C23H27O9 to result. Also target values not just 37 it can also be 74,111,48... Can you update your answer?

Comment: @HarunOz Right, I spotted the ...2709 entry and edited my answer. Have a look now. And clearly you could change the target, by changing the number 37 to whatever you like.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, can you generalize your code? Instead of changing the number can you iterate all numbers and save all results to some data structure it can also be data frame as well.

Comment: @HarunOz Okay, I get it... I edited my answer. This kind of data doesn't really fit into a `pd.DataFrame` though, are you sure that's what you want to do?